# Porting application to android

Tags: android, debugging, testing, emulation, android-hardware

I am about to port my application on android. Since I am new to this system I would like to ask for tips on android phones for testing my app. The number of phones is pretty huge so it is pretty hard to choose the right one. Also I wasn't able to find some kind of official chart of system distribution.

I know that it really depends on hardware and how much my app demands from hardware. It is pretty basic app and I am able to run this app at 30fps on iPhone 4S.

I did some research and people are talking about the latest phones but I think that it is not necessary to buy the newest one. Also, is there option to buy for example tablet and emulate android devices on this tablet?

So my goal is to focus on devices people have the most.

Thank you for any advice.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can run many of your tests on the Android emulator. Using it together
with the [DDMS](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/ddms.html) will allow you to simulate several real life situations
(arriving call, arriving sms, change position...)

You can use [BlueStacks](http://www.bluestacks.com/) which is an emulator put on steroids.

[TestFairy](http://testfairy.com/) and [UTest](http://www.utest.com/) are awsome communities for crowd testing were you can test ~any device you can think of.

Still, it is a good idea, especially if you plan your run at Android to be long,
to maintain a small stash of real devices.


**Which devices should you buy? Which OS version should they run?**


The Android [dashboard](https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html) is the official source for answering some of these questions. It gives an 
up to date statistics of worldwide distribution by OS version, svreen size/density and more:

[image: OS Distribution]

OS Distribution

[image: Screen type Distribution]

Screen type Distribution

So, true to July 2014 you would want devices running Jelly Bean, Gingerbread & ICS and you screens of types normal/hdpi, normal/xxhdpi and normal/xhdpi. This list can grow but even this will provide you with a good sample of the Android device ecosystem.


As for manufacturers, the picture is clear: Samsung is the winner. Exact number &
distributions are harder to find here, but a Google search might help.

If my memory serves me write some 65% of all Android devices are Samsungs made with
Galaxy S3 taking 15% (of ENTIRE Android market) and Galaxy S4 = 10%.

**Device screen features:**

- Galaxy S2 is normal/hdpi
- Galaxy S3 is normal/xhdpi
- Galaxy S4/S5 is normal/xxhdpi

These will probably be your best bet. You will do smartly to install on them 2-3 different OS versions, at
minimum Jelly Bean and ICS.

Answer (score 1):

The Android Development Tools in Eclipse and Android Studio both have emulators that can be used to emulate different devices, including tablets and phones. You don't need to buy anything to be able to test your app on an emulator. The emulators run on your computer.

[For more information](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/emulator.html)

As for what devices most people have, while I don't have official statistics, looking at my own applications' downloads, most people are using either a Nexus 4 or Nexus 5.

Comment: Also I have AdSense in my application and I guess that I can't test this on emulator, right?

Comment: I haven't tried with ads personally, but from a quick google search, it seems as though other people are able to test ads from within an emulator.

Comment: Do you have any info about distribution of android systems?

Comment: No official info on specific devices, but for platform versions you have [this link](https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html) to reference. For phones, your big players are currently the Nexus 4, Nexus 5, and Galaxy S5. These make up about 25% of my most recent app's installs. However, the other 75% are _very_ varied. For tablets, the big player is the Nexus 7 (2013).